# Is shrinkwrap adapted in my situation

Tags: shrinkwrap

I would like to work on the following corridor:
[image: corridor]

First I'v model the metal plate using modifier like this:
[image]

The I would like to combine array+shrinkwarp to fit my corridor shape (cylinder), but it seem all vertices has been impacted:
[image]

I've read on documentation that "*It moves each vertex of the object being modified to the closest position on the surface of the given mesh*", so is there a way to do what I wan't using another method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shrinkwrap is probably not the right tool to use in this situation. You're probably going to want the Simple Deform modifier instead.

If you want to construct your hallway using actual geometry, this is the way you're going to want to go. Arrange your panel so that it's centered at the origin, and then just put in the axis that runs along the length of your panel. You want the Bend mode for the modifier. Your initial mesh will have to have enough geometry to accommodate the bend.

[image]

After you apply the modifier, you will have to move your panel into place. The potentially hard part will be calculating the angle to feed into the modifier, but blender can help you with that too.

Turn on 'Snap'. Make sure it's set to vertex and enabled for rotation. Position your 3D cursor in the center of the hallway, and set the pivot point to 3D cursor. You can then duplicate a vertex and rotate it (in my case around the y-axis). Snap it to other vertices, and you will see in the top left the amount of rotation to feed into the Simple Deform modifier.

[image]

Once you apply the modifier, you can use the Snap tool to move, rotate, and scale the panel into place. I use 3D cursor as the pivot point, and Active Vertex as the Snap element so that I can precisely control what I'm doing:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and this solution! I'll try it thx!!!

Comment: simle deform (bend) + snap rotation on vertex (using 3D cursor) solve my problem.
Thanks again Rekov